# how to use pdf library in php?

Tags: php, pdf

When i start it's showing this error

```
 <?php
     $p = PDF_new();
 ?>
```

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function PDF_new() in D:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 2
```

I am using Wamp Server. I tried in XAMPP also. Is there any directives i have to enable to execute the code ?

Comment: or, download TCPDF, personally I find that better.

Answer (score 5):

i suggest to you [tcpdf](http://tcpdf.org). it was good for me.
some feature:

- no external libraries are required
  for the basic functions;
- all standard    page formats, custom
  page formats,    custom margins and
  units of measure;
- UTF-8 Unicode and Right-To-Left
  languages;

Comment: Thanks for this, its help me a lot and pretty easy to start on ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think [http://www.fpdf.org/](http://www.fpdf.org) is the best PDF library for PHP.
Download latest version from [http://www.fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/).
Put this library folder on your root server or in your project.
Create on test file named test.php & put below code in file as below.

```
<?php
include("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',36);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

It will create one pdf file with contents "Hello World!" in it.
You are done..

Comment: I get this error 
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�r Q�w3T04�30PISp  �Z*�[����(hx(�*�d�*����($�+j*�d�4�� endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 5 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.7) /CreationDate (D:20130806153215) >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 8  00000 n 0000000324 00000 n 0000000529 00000 n 0000000604 00000 n trailer << /Size 8 /Root 7 0 R /Info 6 0 R >> startxref 653 %%EOF